# Detect if columns were added or removed in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

How can I get notified if a columns in a QTableWidget have been added or removed? Is there a signal or an event for that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after a while (it wasn't very obvious cause they're called sections):

```
connect(ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(sectionCountChanged(int,int)), SLOT(onSectionCountChanged(int,int)));
```

Comment: Since QTableWidget is an QAbstractItemView, and so is backed by a Qt model, you can use that for a "generic" solution. Get the backing model via tableWidget->model() and connect to its rich set of signals (e.g. columnsInserted, columnsMoved, columnsRemoved, ...)